# How to immitate Devise's sign_in(@user) helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I tried in do it like this in application_controller.rb

```
helper_method: sign_in

def sign_in(email, password)
        valid_params = { email: email, password: password }
        post login_path, params: valid_params
end
```

is this a best way ?

Comment: Could you please expand on what you are trying to achieve? Thanks

Comment: @MarkAllen Devise gem has a helper method that is very convinient I normally use sign_in method when I am testing using Rspec like so: `sign_in(@admin)`, what it does is it signs in the user given. Now I am not using Devise therefore wanted to imitate that helper method.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I like to do is

```
class Admins::UsersController < AdminController
  ...
  def login_as
    sign_in(User.find(params[:user_id]), :bypass => true)
    redirect_to users_root_path
  end
end
```

you should not pass a user_id but some sort of key or a uuid but you get the gist

Comment: Please can you elaborate on what you did here?
So sign_in is not a method specific only to Devise? and what is bypass?